# Error on realloc when try to allocate more memory

Tags: c, linux, malloc, realloc

Iam developing a function where the size of array starts with 10, if the string of fgets its bigger he needs to allocate more memory, but I get a error, when the string is too big, like if I type something with 15 chars its ok, but with 30 I got the error! And I dont know why. So I hope you can tell me.

-= **SOLVED ON THIS CODE** =-

**My main:**

```
char *buf;

shellExecute(&buf);
```

**My code:**

```
 char* shellExecute(char** buf){
    
        int bufSize = 10;
        *buf = malloc(bufSize * sizeof(char));
        if(*buf == NULL){
            printf("[ERROR] can't malloc %d bytes\n", bufSize);
            exit(0);
        }
        char *readpos = *buf;
        
        while (1){  
        
        fgets(readpos, bufSize, stdin);
    
        /* Search from the end, as there's where the newline should be */
            if (readpos[strlen(readpos)-1] == '\n'){
                break;
            }   
    
        /* Need to allocate more memory */
             bufSize += bufSize;
             *buf = realloc(*buf, *buf + strlen(*buf) * sizeof(char));
    
        /* Set the pointer to next position to read into */
            readpos = *buf + strlen(*buf);
        /* Loop takes case of trying again */
        }   
    }
```

**My error:**

[image]

Comment: Use a debugger and step through the code....

Comment: What's the point of passing `char**` if you `return *buf` it anyway?

Comment: @KamilCuk Thats not the problem, because, I already had a void func and still with error

Comment: Please don't edit the question and/or answer with your fixed code.  They only make sense when they're about the incorrect code, and they may help people who have similar incorrect code of their own.  If you want to give an update as to how you fixed the problem, post your own answer instead.

Comment: @NateEldredge Ok, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The total size starts as 10.  You do

```
fgets(readpos, bufSize, stdin);
```

On the first iteration, `readpos` points to the start of the buffer, so this is fine.  Let's say 9 bytes are read, leaving space for the null terminator.  You now do

```
bufSize += bufSize;
*buf = realloc(*buf, bufSize * sizeof(char));
```

So now `bufSize` is 20, and `*buf` has a total size of 20.  Next you do

```
readpos = *buf + strlen(*buf);
```

so that `readpos` now points to `*buf+9`.

Your next `fgets` will attempt to read 20 bytes into a buffer of total size 20, but starting at offset 9, beyond which only 11 bytes are available.  This may overrun the buffer by 9 bytes, causing undefined behavior.

Probably you want to keep a separate count of how many bytes have actually been read, and use this to calculate the space remaining in the buffer, which you will pass to `fgets`.

Another bug is that you need to check the return value of `fgets` to determine when the file has ended or if an error occurs.  As it stands, when either of those things happens, your program will loop infinitely.

Comment: So, I need to reformulate this `readpos = *buf + strlen(*buf);` putting `readpos = *buf;`?

Comment: @prt05: That will avoid the buffer overrun, but then you'll be overwriting the previously read data with the new data instead of appending, which I don't think is what you want.